# MVC 4 Route mapping isn't working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have a website that I've recently added File Attachment functionality to; however, the Kendo `.SaveUrl()` doesn't seem to "see" the controller! I've verified that all the file paths are correct. I've added the custom map before the default mapping statement... The browser isn't the issue, I've tried IE, Chrome, FireFox and Safari, same error. Please help!

The Error:

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The controller for path '/Shared/RepairAttachment' was not found or does not implement IController.
```

The map in Global.asax.cs:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "/Shared/RepairAttachment",
            url: "Controllers/RepairAttachmentsController/{Save}/{IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>}",
            defaults: new { controller = "RepairAttachmentsController", action = "Save", attachments = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

The file uploader code:

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
        .ShowFileList(true)
        .Async(async => async
            .SaveUrl("SharedRepairAttachment")
        )
        .Name("frmUploadController")
        .Multiple(true)
        .Events(events => events
            .Complete("onRepairAttachmentUploadComplete")
            .Error("onRepairAttachmentUploadError")
        )
    )
```

The Controller (partial):

```
public class RepairAttachmentsController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [HttpOptions]
    public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> attachments)
    {
        try
        {
            HarbisonFischerDBEntities db = new HarbisonFischerDBEntities();
            foreach (var file in attachments)
            {
                Repair r = db.Repairs.Find(ViewBag.RepairID);
                // Each Customer and repair gets their own folder
                string srvrpath = Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerPathForFiles"].ToString(), r.CustomerLocation.Customer.OracleName);
                srvrpath = Path.Combine(srvrpath, r.RepairID.ToString());
                if (Directory.Exists(srvrpath) == false) { Directory.CreateDirectory(srvrpath); }

                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);  // Some browsers send file names with full path; we only care about the file name.
                string destinationPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(srvrpath), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(destinationPath);

                RepairAttachment ra = new RepairAttachment();
                ra.FileName = file.FileName;
                ra.Title = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);
                ra.RepairID = ViewBag.RepairID;
                db.RepairAttachments.Add(ra);
                db.SaveChanges();                
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logic.ExceptionLogging.LogException("RepairAttachmentsController", ex, null, null);
            return Json(new { status = "Upload Failed: " + ex.Message }, "text/plain");
        }
        return Json(new { status = "Upload succeeded." }, "text/plain");
    }
```

Comment: The error says `/Shared/RepairAttachment`, shouldn't that read `/Shared/RepairAttachments`?

Comment: Your Url format is interesting... Never seen "{IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>}" as parameter - not sure how/if it works... Note that your sample does not show route that matches "/Shared/RepairAttachment" url - consider adding to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Kendo, but I have a hard time thinking this will work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "/Shared/RepairAttachment",
            url: "Controllers/RepairAttachmentsController/{Save}/{IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>}",
            defaults: new { controller = "RepairAttachmentsController", action = "Save", attachments = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

If you are sending a request to "/Shared/RepairAttachment", the pattern in your `url` parameter should match this. So, I would expect you to need something like

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "RepairAttachment",
            url: "/Shared/RepairAttachment",
            defaults: new { controller = "RepairAttachments", action = "Save", attachments = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Notice how I

- changed the value of the `url` parameter to match the incoming request
- removed "Controller" from "RepairAttachmentsController" as it isn't needed unless your controller is named "RepairAttachmentsControllerController"
- removed the "{IEnumerable...}" stuff altogether. I know you are trying to tell MVC that you will be sending a collection of files, but you don't declare that here. [MVC's model binding features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx) will figure it out on its own because your action method takes an `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> attachments` argument.

Comment: Rune, I do believe that you've resolved my routing issue! I'm still getting an error, but the code is at least finding the right file. I have to figure out why: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): A public action method 'Save' was not found on controller 'HarbisonFischer.Web.Controllers.RepairAttachmentsController'.

Comment: By having both [HttpPost] and [HttpOptions] on the action method you require that the request be a POST request AND an OPTIONS request, but it is impossible for it to be both, so the action will never be considered valid. Try removing those attributes.

Comment: This is so strange... If I remove the [HttpPost] and [HttpOptions] completely, then the error becomes: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): A public action method 'Index' was not found on controller... Yet, clearly, the Index() is there. If I add either [HttpGet] or [HttpPost], then the Save() cannot be seen.

Comment: Btw, per the Kendo docs, I am certain that the Save() needs to be a [HttpPost]...

Comment: Ok, per my last post... Unrelated error, I didn't read it closely enough; my bad entirely. Thank you to all who posted! Rune, I would upvote your response if I were allowed to. :-)